# SOSL record limit

Tags: apex

I have a SOSL,

```
string coc = 'coc';
String searchquery='FIND \'*'+coc+'*\'IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING '+
                        'Account(Id, Name,Type,Global_DUNS_Number__c, DUNS_Number__c, VAT_Number__c,Segment__c, Registered_Country__c ,OwnerID,Owner.Name,Owner.opco__c,Owner.UserType, Owner.ContactId LIMIT 201 ), '+
                        'Contact(Id, Name, Email, Account.Name,Generic_Job_Role__c, Owner.opco__C ,Country__c, Owner.Name,OwnerID,Owner.UserType, Owner.ContactId LIMIT 201), '+
                        'Lead(Id, Name, Company, Email,Macro_Segment__c, Owner.Name,OwnerID  LIMIT 201), '+
                        'Opportunity(Id, Name, Account.Name, Owner.Name limit 0) ';
List<List<SObject>>searchList = search.query(searchquery);
```

I have saved this code against API version 28.

'System Query exception:Maximum entity limit is 200'

I thought for  v.28  and above, limit is 2000?

Also when i execute this in my eclipse ide,it gives me same error.and i can see

```
DEBUG LOG
27.0 APEX_CODE,DEBUG;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;VALIDATION,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
```

where do i change this 27.0?i thought anonymous executes in latest version?

Comment: You're right, it is 2000 with v28 - http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_sosl_limits.htm

Comment: Yeah but you know why it behaves strangely.Infact it used to work and suddenly changed//Not sure why.does api version change automatically? also in anonymous block,it shows version 27.i thought anonymous gets executed in latest version?

Comment: Is the project you have open in Eclipse using v27 or v28?

Comment: where do i see that?

Comment: You may need to update your Eclipse plugin so it is using the latest version. http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Updating_the_Force.com_IDE

Comment: Actually, check the version of your IDE. In the menu, select Help -> About Force.com IDE and it'll tell you the version. Alternately, when you add a new Apex class you'll see a drop-down for version number.

Comment: Yes it works in my anonymous block when i updated Plugin.